# Replace toast into alert dialog

Tags: android

```
sas12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "                                                                    ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        LinearLayout toastView = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
        ImageView imageCodeProject = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageCodeProject.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
        toastView.addView(imageCodeProject, 0);
        toast.show();               
    }
});
```

This is my code..that when a `text(textview)` is clicked..a `Toast` with image will appear "`imageCodeProject.setImageResource(R.drawable.image)`"..then i want it to execute by using an Alert dialog so that i can end it manually.

here is an example of what i want to happen..

```
Fevertxt = fever image
```

"`Fevertxt`" is the `TextView` and "fever image" is an image that will show what a fever looks like..

Comment: i think no because it is placed inside an sas12..@Raghunandan

Comment: exactly same question. What's the problem? Why don't you just use an alert dialog...?!

Comment: yes.the problem is i have no idea on how to convert that toast in an alert dialog..sorry guys..i'm just a beginner in android @ElDuderino

Answer (score 0):

To create an AlertDialog, do the following...

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Hi").setMessage("I am an AlertDialog").create().show();
```

Comment: but how can i add image in my alert dialog.? @Elduderino